# How to separate images of graphs?

Tags: python-3.x, networkx, graph-theory

I need to draw these complete graphs that the edges of the separate graphs don't intersect intercept each other. I have tried to use coordinates in matplotlib but it didn't work. That is the code:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


G=nx.Graph()
G.add_edge("1", "2")
G.add_edge("2","3")
G.add_edge("3","4")
G.add_edge("1","3")
G.add_edge("1","4")
G.add_edge("2","4")

pos = {1: (0, 0), 2: (1, 1), 3: (0, 1) , 4: (1, 0)}
        
F=nx.Graph()
F.add_edge("5", "6")
F.add_edge("6","7")
F.add_edge("7","8")
F.add_edge("5","7")
F.add_edge("5","8")
F.add_edge("6","8")

pos = {5: (10, 10), 6: (11, 11), 7: (10, 11) , 8: (11, 10)}

E=nx.Graph()
E.add_edge("9", "10")
E.add_edge("10","11")
E.add_edge("9","11")

pos = nx.random_layout(E)

Y=nx.Graph()
Y.add_node("12")

pos = nx.random_layout(Y)

nx.draw(G, with_labels = True, node_color = 'white')
nx.draw(F, with_labels = True, node_color = 'white')
nx.draw(E, with_labels = True, node_color = 'white')
nx.draw(Y, with_labels = True, node_color = 'white')

plt.savefig('labels.png')
plt.show()
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Can you please clarify what the term "edges of the separate graphs don't intersect intercept each other" means?  Also, is the result what you want or what you are getting.  If it is what you want, what does your code produce.  If it is what you are getting, can you provide what you are expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create the `pos` variable and overwrite it multiple times without using it at any point. Simply create multiple with non overlapping drawing areas:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edge("1", "2")
G.add_edge("2", "3")
G.add_edge("3", "4")
G.add_edge("1", "3")
G.add_edge("1", "4")
G.add_edge("2", "4")

pos_G = {"1": (0, 0), "2": (1, 1), "3": (0, 1), "4": (1, 0)}

F = nx.Graph()
F.add_edge("5", "6")
F.add_edge("6", "7")
F.add_edge("7", "8")
F.add_edge("5", "7")
F.add_edge("5", "8")
F.add_edge("6", "8")

pos_F = {"5": (10, 10), "6": (11, 11), "7": (10, 11), "8": (11, 10)}

E = nx.Graph()
E.add_edge("9", "10")
E.add_edge("10", "11")
E.add_edge("9", "11")

pos_E = nx.random_layout(E)
pos_E = {node: pos + 3 for node, pos in pos_E.items()}

Y = nx.Graph()
Y.add_node("12")

pos_Y = nx.random_layout(Y)
pos_Y = {node: pos + 5 for node, pos in pos_Y.items()}

nx.draw(G, pos_G, with_labels=True, node_color='white')
nx.draw(F, pos_F, with_labels=True, node_color='white')
nx.draw(E, pos_E, with_labels=True, node_color='white')
nx.draw(Y, pos_Y, with_labels=True, node_color='white')

# plt.savefig('labels.png')
plt.show()
```

#### Result

[image]